# A 90 degree turn with Wheel part number 56145

Tags: ev3, programming, robotic

I'm making a program for my ev3rstorm and I want it to have a 90-degree [spin turn](http://www.education.rec.ri.cmu.edu/content/electronics/boe/robot_motion/5.html). I use the standard part ev3rstorm wheelbase or rather, treadbase. Using the move tank block (I use that block all the time) how long should I move back/forward at 75/-75 power?

Wheel picture:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use your gyroscope sensor, set your program to have the Move Tank block turn very slowly in the "On" mode, and then use a Wait block checking the Gyro sensor until it sees an absolute change of 90 degrees. Then add a Move Tank "Off" block. That's the closest you will come to 90 degrees.